# Highcharts - Column chart - How to change column alignments?

Tags: highcharts, angular-highcharts

I have column chart in 3D. I know I can set alpha, beta and depth properties to change the angle. but in a latest requirement, I cannot set these angles to achieve required viewing angles.

[Currently it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT8EM.png)

[Desired look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iTrF.png)

I have tried setting options3d.alhpa,beta,depth angles to achieve this angle. but didn't find any luck.

Comment: Columns follow the axis's perspective, so it's difficult to recreate your image example 1:1. What about the following settings http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j3ygkue6/ ? You can also use the following draggable tool to check what perspective is the best for your requirements https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sk9r710v/